# platform to store, sell and buy content?

Tags: file-management

i'm looking for a platform that will help me have "partner" users upload their content and then sell it to "customer users", so it can manage authentication for the "partner" to be able to upload and edit his content and only the "customer" who purchased the content can download it.

the content to store will be a compressed directory(zip or rar)  that will hold portable databases, images, texts, and songs.

the user will build the product on their local computer and when its ready it will be uploaded and host it in the platform so other users can buy it and download it with their own client application.

i'm expecting the compressed file to hold from 500mb to 5gb of data

users can store 1 or many of these products, 
something desirable is the capability of creating a profile for the "partner" user, and for the customer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Wix.com has plugins for those needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I see with Wix i can upload and sell content access, but it won't let my partners upload their own content, 

it seems like a good initial platform to do some manual work to set things in place

Comment: That's not a software recommendation (you cannot download and install it), it's a service recommendation, which IMHO is off-topic.